# How to get a video stream from google could storage object that is able to seek

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, video-streaming

I'm streaming a video file from a cloud storage bucket in an express.js server and was able to successfully pipe that stream to a video element in the frontend. However, since the video content is now loaded progressively, I can't seek through the loaded video.

My node.js code for getting a video stream from a cloud storage object is as follows.

```js
async function getVideoStream(gcloudFileName,res){
  const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET);
  const remoteFile = bucket.file(gcloudFileName);
  return remoteFile.createReadStream().pipe(res)
}
```

**How can I make this video stream possible to seek so that users can seek through the video on the frontend?**
Helpful suggestions are highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried with @Rafael's answer and got it working up to some extent, but now the problem is the stream stops after delivering the first few chunks of the video. Also at the same time, the video also stops playing.

[image]

Comment: Http range requests.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use ranged requests, as mentioned in @szatmary comment, so that the server can send chunks of the file at a time instead of the whole thing, you can find a complete explanation in [this article](https://dev.to/abdisalan_js/how-to-code-a-video-streaming-server-using-nodejs-2o0), but applied to your code you can do the following:

```
async function getVideoStream(req,res){
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (!range) {
    res.status(400).send("Requires Range header");
  }
  const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET);
  // I added the file name to your request's body
  const remoteFile = bucket.file(req.body);

  //calculates the chunck to be sent based on the video size
  const videoSize = remoteFile.getMetadata().size;
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6; // 1MB
  const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);

  // Create headers
  const contentLength = end - start + 1;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": contentLength,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  };

  // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
  res.writeHead(206, headers);

  //returns the chunk that you want
  return remoteFile.createReadStream({ start, end }).pipe(res)
}
```

Comment: @rafael Thanks for your detailed answer with the sample code. Now only I got time to test this. I'm a little bit confused as the `headers` object is not used anywhere. Can you please show me how to provide it to the `createReadStream` function?

Comment: actually I forgot to add the line that adds it to the response sorry about that, you can see it in the example of the shared link. Never the less I added it to the code sample.

Comment: Hello @rafael, I have been trying the code sample you provided for some days, but only the first chunk of the video is playing and after that, the video is not loading altogether. Can you please give me some advice to avoid this problem? I will open another question if you think it's suitable.

Comment: I also edited the question with the latest troubleshooting details. will be a huge help if you can have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: @RafaelLemos any idea on how I might debug this? for some reason I can't get videos to load and the on('error') callback never gets invoked.

Comment: on('end'), on('finish'), and on('close') also do not get invoked

Answer (score 0):

I did that kind of implementation and it worked pretty well and it's pretty simple

I m using my business API as a proxi to get my files

Cloud => node server => front

API service:

```js
  streamFileDownload: (fileName) => bucket.file(fileName).createReadStream(),
```

API contoller :

```js
  server.get<GetStorageDocumentRoute>(
      '/getDocument',
      {
        schema: GetStorageDocumentSchema,
      },
      async (req, reply) => {
        const stream = cloudStorageService.streamFileDownload(
          link // path of your file in the bucket based on your service
        )

        reply.headers({
          'Content-Type': mimeType,
          'Content-Disposition': `inline; filename="${name}"; mimeType="${mimeType}"`,
        })
        return reply.send(stream)
      },
    )
```