# expressJS pipe video from GCS

Tags: express, google-cloud-storage, pipe

I am sure this question has been asked a million times, but I am having issues with the following script. It works fine in Safari browsers but not Firefox or Chrome.

```
app.get('/stream', async (req, res) => {
  const bucket = storage.bucket("REMOVED");
  const file = bucket.file("syndication/2023/09/1696116750736video_Kelly_finished.mp4");

  const stat = await file.getMetadata();
  const fileSize = stat[0].size;
  res.set({
    "Content-Length": fileSize.toString(),
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    Connection: "Keep-Alive",
    "Keep-Alive": "timeout=2, max=100",
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    "X-Accel-Buffering": "no"
  });
  
  // Pipe the video stream to the response
  const stream = file.createReadStream();

  stream.pipe(res)
});
```

I am wondering if anyone knows how to pipe a video file.

It works fine when it's a mp3.

When I code it like this

```
app.get('/stream', async (req, res) => {
  const fileStream = storage.bucket("REMOVED").file("syndication/2023/09/1696116750736video_Kelly_finished.mp4");
  const [metadata] = await fileStream.getMetadata();
  const fileSize = metadata.size;
 
  // Set appropriate headers to allow the audio to play in the browser and track streaming duration
  res.set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
  res.set('Content-Length', fileSize.toString()); // Convert fileSize to a string
  res.set('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
  //res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=3600'); // Cache the file for 1 hour (adjust as needed)

  fileStream.createReadStream().pipe(res);
});
```

it works in microsoft edge (chrome) but not Firefox

Comment: When one is developing service dealing with videos, it's important to understand range requests. You can do so by reading the HTTP/1.1 specification which includes [RFC 7233][1] outlining how range requests should be formatted.

Chrome, Firefox and other major browsers use that standard so that one only needs to code once (I'm surprised it's working in Safari).

There's a good example on [how to use them here][2]


  [1]: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7233
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104306/5675325

Comment: Found out the issue was the codec H.246 - you can use those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the codec used it should not use any h.264 or h.265

I am not sure why some mp4 work but I know when I encoded the videos with

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_VIDEO -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset medium -b:v 1M -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p $OUTPUT_VIDEO
```

It worked.